# Meta reputation is not in sync with the main reputation

Tags: bug

When my main account's reputation is 40, the meta account still shows me as 28 reputation. Where is the problem?

Comment: Displayed reputation is not calculated in real time with every page load. If the wrong cached value persists for more than a few hours, I would submit a bug report.

Comment: I'm certain this question has come up before with a link to the appropriate MSE thread, but I haven't put my finger on it yet.

Comment: It take me 2 hours to update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes some time for the reputation to update. See for example [Reputation shown different in Stackoverflow and Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284058/7443472):

> Reputation takes time to update between websites. You just hadn't waited long enough. You see this sometimes even between SO and MSO - there is a time delay between when you receive reputation and when your profile on other sites will display it. Waiting ~15 minutes should give it enough time to update.